# How can I make collection in Cloud Firestore that can be user reordered without writing every document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I have a checklist collection where each item is it's own document since it contains a lot of other data.

I want the user to be able to drag and drop to reorder this list an save it that way.  My initial thought was to have a field that is changed to reflect this order but moving one object requires changing the value on every document that is after the new location.

Is there a way to achieve this without a massive number of writes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of documents changes frequently, you can avoid writing the contents of each document by instead using a whole different document to maintain the order, using an array of strings containing the document IDs.  In fact, you could hold lots of different orderings depending on how you want to display the documents.

Say you have a collection of documents:

```
collection
  - docA
  - docB
  - docC
```

Now you want to store mutable orderings in a document called "order" in another collection:

```
collection-meta
  - order
    - byAlpha: ["docA", "docB", "docC"]
    - byScore: ["docC", "docA", "docB"]
```

Just query the "order" document first, then get each document for display in the order defined in the array.  To reorder the documents, just update the contents of the single array in the "order" doc.

Comment: A note in regard to corruption when also adding/deleting entries is possible: the ordering must be blocked while adding/deleting entries and as firestore is local-first, this isn't feasible only client-side. As when sending the whole array from one client, another client may have added something, which can't exist yet in the array from the other client (who just moved something).

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this by using a floating point value for the order.

Say you have a list with these 3 documents:

- ID=a, order=1.0
- ID=b, order=2.0
- ID=c, order=3.0

Now let's assume we want to move document `a` between `b` and `c`. You'd do that by changing its order to `2.0 + (3.0 - 2.0) / 2` = `2.5`.

- ID=b, order=2.0
- ID=a, order=2.5
- ID=c, order=3.0

This works for a reasonable number of swaps, which is the scenario I usually deal with.

If you're dealing with a large number/potentially infinite of iterations, you'll want to look at the precision of the floating point operation. In that case your alternative might be to use a custom value type, i.e. encoding the value into a string field and then use a custom library to do the division at a higher numeric precision.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, what you can do is You can have a separate document that contains index of all the other checklist document. All the checklist documents can keep their respective info as it is supposed to be. For example

```
Checklist1                  Checklist3           
Checklist2                  Checklist2
Checklist3                  Checklist1
Index                       Index
(Before)                    (After Drag)
```

and Index contains structure like below after the drag is performed:

```
  Index   ->   field         value  
               Checklist1    3  
               Checklist2    2
               Checklist3    1
```